# CefSharp C# How would I get the link to the current website?

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I'm using CefSharp for a little project me and my friend are working on, and we want to get the link to the current site, then put it into a TextBox, but we can't find any way to get the link of the site we are currently on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the WinForms example at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/blob/master/CefSharp.MinimalExample.WinForms/BrowserForm.cs. There is a OnBrowse change event that receives the URL of the browser once it's loaded.